# MySql function not using indexes

Tags: mysql, function

I have simple function consist of one sql query

```
CREATE FUNCTION `GetProductIDFunc`( in_title char (14) )
        RETURNS bigint(20)
BEGIN
  declare out_id bigint;    

  select id into out_id from products where title = in_title limit 1;    
  RETURN out_id;
END
```

Execution time of this function takes 5 seconds

```
select Benchmark(500 ,GetProductIdFunc('sample_product'));
```

Execution time of plain query takes 0.001 seconds

```
select Benchmark(500,(select id from products where title = 'sample_product' limit 1));
```

"Title" field is indexed. Why function execution takes so much time and how can I optimize it?

*edit:*
Execution plan

```
mysql> EXPLAIN EXTENDED select id from products where title = 'sample_product' limit 1;
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | products | const | Index_title   | Index_title | 14      | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN select GetProductIdFunc('sample_product');
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | NULL  | NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL | No tables used |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: can you include the execution plan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a character set issue. If the function is using a different character set than the table column, it would lead to very slow performance despite the index.

Run `show create table products\G` to determine the character set for the column.

Run `show variables like 'character_set%';` to see what the relevant default character sets are for your DB.

Comment: Brilliant. 
How to force procedure to use correct character set.

Comment: You can specify a character set for the input parameter. For example `CREATE FUNCTION GetProductIDFunc( in_title char (14) charset utf8)...`

Comment: Another option is to explicitly convert the charset of in_title when comparing it to title: `select id into out_id from products where title = convert(in_title using utf8) limit 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `GetProductIDFunc`( in_title char (14) )
        RETURNS bigint(20)
BEGIN
  declare out_id bigint;    

  set out_id = (select id from products where title = in_title limit 1);    
  RETURN out_id;
END
```